# WordPress Multisite Customize Error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress multisite build with 9 different themes running. Everything is working okay, I've used Redux Framework on most of them but I'm not able to use the native WordPress customizer, I receive the generic, "Cheatin’ uh? Sorry, you are not allowed to customize this site." error. I am a super admin so I don't believe it's a permissions issue. I'm not able to use the customizer on any of the sites, so I'm thinking it's a core issue but I'm not sure where to look. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work on a theme that's not Redux?

Comment: No it doesn't, I actually noticed it on a theme I purchased that doesn't use Redux, just the native hook: add_action( 'customize_register', 'register_theme_customizer' );

Comment: Try to create a new admin user and retry

Comment: Enabling debug and debug_log may show some info: [Debugging - WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wordpress/9170/debugging#t=201705231658258251565)

Answer (score 0):

Many people have same issue after update to WordPress 4.7x.

I see someone fixed this issue using this method:

```
install the plug-in [User Role Editor][1]
go to Users->User Role Editor
select Role: Administrator at the top
check the row edit_theme_options
click on Update
confirm the message box
```

Comment: um this is interesting, I installed that plugin but when I go to the editor, I don't have Administrator as an option, just up to Author.

Comment: What is your permission?

Comment: I am a Admin/Super Admin. I was able to enable admin role in the drop down but it edit_theme_options was already checked and unchecking/rechecking didn't work either.

Comment: Same thing here :(. Weirdly enough I can't even use the customizer with a newly created user with the Administrator role.